# How Many Paths Go From Point A to B Such That Every Space is Passed Through Once

Tags: combinatorics, hamiltonian-path

Given the following grid where it is only possible to move between squares that share an edge, how many paths are there that visit every single square exactly once?

[image: Image of the Grid]

From what I can think of, I know that the two squares sticking out on the left and right side are the start and end points but other than that I'm stuck.

Can I have a hint?

Comment: This can be rewritten as a question about a Hamilton path on the adjacency graph. You are correct about the endpoints.

Comment: Hint: color them black and white like a chessboard. What colors are the start and end point? How many squares are there?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Since you start and end on the same colour, one colour has been reached more than the other.